# How to show S3 private access Image/video in play framework scala application

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, playframework, playframework-2.0

**Aim:**

I have a S3 video url and S3 Image url. The S3 bucket have private access(Not public). I have a "Access Key Id" and "Secret Access Key" to access the S3 bucket. I have to show the S3 Image/video in the screen without storing in local. I am using play framework 2.5.3 and scala language.

**What I tried:**

I have searched in the internet. I got the below plugins to use S3.

https://github.com/seratch/AWScala

https://github.com/Kaliber/play-s3

By using the above plugins we can read the image/video file content. But I don't want to read the whole file content. I want to show the Image/video in the view without storing in local.

**What I want:**

It would be help if anybody give their suggestion.

1) Is it possible to play video and Show Images from the S3 URL with the use of "Access Key Id" and "Secret Access Key" in my play scala application.

2) If yes, kindly please share the way to do this. Thanks!!!

**Updated 24-05-2016:**

I have tried the below way:

```
def loadS3File() = Action { implicit request =>
        try {
            val bucket = S3("user")
            val result = bucket get "user.png"
            val file = Await.result(result, 10 seconds)
            val BucketFile(name, contentType, content, acl, headers) = file
            Ok.chunked(Enumerator(content)).as(contentType);
        }
        catch {
            case e: Exception =>
                BadRequest("Error: " + e.getMessage)
        }
    }
```

But I did get the below exception - **Error:: orginalUri**

What is wrong in the above implementation?

Comment: You cannot do this without reading the whole file contents. Nothing forces you to store it as a file on the server, but you do have to read the whole file so that you can serve it. You can serve it by hooking up a route to a controller that uses play-s3 to read the file contents and serve it directly, and referencing that route in an img tag (in the case of an image file).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I 'll try it.

Comment: @RobinGreen I have updated my impl code in the question. I am facing some issues. Can you please look and help me to fix the issue. Thanks.

Comment: You need to log the stack trace so you can see the details of the error.

Comment: @RobinGreen, Yes I got it worked now. The issue is because of the configuration. Thank you so much for the response. Now I am facing other two issues. 
1) It waits for the whole file to read and it streamed after that only. How do I play a video without waiting for whole file to download.
2) Await.result(result, 10 seconds). It throws timeout exception after 10 seconds. I shouldn't set the static time. Because each file has its own size. so it take time to stream.
Can you please help on this to proceed further.

Comment: Please raise new questions on Stackoverflow for these problems.

Comment: @RobinGreen Posted SO question for the issue. http://stackoverflow.com/q/37430684/1584121